# SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin not working on Spring MVC

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using the following components in my REST back-end project:

- Spring MVC: 4.1.2.RELEASE (latest)
- Hibernate4 Object Mapper: 2.4.3 (latest)
- Swagger: 0.9.1 (latest)
- Javaee-web-api: 7.0 (servlet 3.1)

I'm using XML based bean configuration and I was able to get the basic setup with Swagger up and running, using the following in Spring XML Configuration file:

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven/> <!-- Required so swagger-springmvc can access spring's RequestMappingHandlerMapping  -->

 <bean class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig" />
```

I then cloned the Swagger-UI GIT repo from https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui and copied of the dist folder to my */webapp/docs* folder. After doing so I was able to use the JS based UI on the following URL:

```
http://localhost:9090/docs/index.html (works so far).
```

The problem is that none of the **try it out** buttons worked, which can be used to interact with your REST API using JSON directly. The reason that it did not work is that it did not take the correct **base url path** to talk to my controllers:

```
http://localhost:9090/rest/addresses (actual controller location)
http://localhost:9090/addresses (swagger's attempt to talk to the API)
```

After some research online I found out that I probably better go for the more flexible approach using SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin as documented on https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc.

This is my **swagger configuration class** file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
public class MySwaggerConfig {

    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;

    @Autowired
    public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig) {
        this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation(){
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
                .includePatterns(".*");
    }
}
```

This is my full **spring mvc xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="be.exampley.backend.web.rest"/>

    <bean id="hibernateAwareObjectMapper" class="be.example.backend.util.HibernateAwareObjectMapper"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"
                  p:prettyPrint="true"
                  p:supportedMediaTypes-ref="supportedMediaTypes"
                  p:objectMapper-ref="hibernateAwareObjectMapper"/>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <util:list id="supportedMediaTypes">
        <value>application/json</value>
        <value>text/plain</value>
    </util:list>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:swagger.properties"/>

    <bean name="swaggerConfig" class="be.example.backend.configuration.MySwaggerConfig"/>

</beans>
```

An extract of the relevant section from my **web.xml** file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/mvc-rest-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is my **swagger.properties** file, which is not taken into account at all for some reason.

```
documentation.services.basePath=/rest/
documentation.services.version=2.0
```

The stacktrace I get during application startup:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySwaggerConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void be.example.backend.configuration.MySwaggerConfig.setSpringSwaggerConfig(com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.List com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig.handlerMappings; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] found for dependency [collection of org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:789)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:557)
...
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] found for dependency [collection of org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:600)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:789)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:557)
```

I read somewhere that the *No qualifying bean of type org...RequestMappingHandlerMapping* trace suggests I might miss **mvc:annotation-driven** in my XML, but this is not the case.

I have been searching for hours now to find a solution, but failed so far. The fact that in it's basic configuration (using **SpringSwaggerConfig**) it's working for 90% (besides the **try it out** button...), makes me not want to give up on swagger just yet. It really seems very cool and is a good way of documenting your API.

So if anyone can help me out on this one, I would be very gratefull. Swagger rocks!

Kind regards,
Bart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was probably stumbling upon the following issue,  "No matching bean was found for auto-wiring" for RequestMappingHandlerMapping: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/112154-unable-to-autowire-requestmappinghandlermapping-in-controller

In the mean while I have switched to *Java based configuration* to replace my XML. This solved the autowire issue as well. Hereby my solution for other's reference, which includes changing the **apiResourcePrefix** and ussing a **swagger.properties** file for external configuration.

My **web.xml** file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/business.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>be.example.backend.configuration.MvcConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My **bussiness.xml** as root application context:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="be.example.backend"/>
...
```

My **MvcConfig.java** as MVC configuration file:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"be.example.backend"})
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(new HibernateAwareObjectMapper());
        converter.setPrettyPrint(true);
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);
        converters.add(converter);

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

My **SwaggerConfig.java** as swagger configuration file:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger
@PropertySource("classpath:swagger.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"be.example.backend"})
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig implements ServletContextAware {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;

    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Autowired
    public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig) {
        this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation() {
        RelativeSwaggerPathProvider relativeSwaggerPathProvider = new RelativeSwaggerPathProvider(servletContext);
        relativeSwaggerPathProvider.setApiResourcePrefix(environment.getProperty("swagger.resource_prefix"));
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
                .pathProvider(relativeSwaggerPathProvider);
    }


    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }
}
```

My **swagger.properties** external properties file:

```
swagger.resource_prefix=rest
```

This solution worked for me and I am now able to enjoy the swagger features through swagger-ui.

Hope others can enjoy it as well!

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same exception

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'mySwaggerConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: 
public void be.example.backend.configuration.MySwaggerConfig.setSpringSwaggerConfig
(com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig)
```

in my test. Root casue was incorrect annotation. My test was annotated with *@Integration*, rather than with *@WebIntegrationTest*.

For production code, make sure your *@Configuration* is annotated with *@EnableWebMvc*